# How to update (not override) exsiting load balancer by adding new public IP through ARM template in Azure

Tags: json, azure, azure-load-balancer

i have a existing external load balancer with a public IP associated to it. i want to update another new exiting public IP(Basically adding multiple public IP to a load balancer). i am trying to do with ARM template. can anyone give the solution to add new IP without overriding the previous one. 
**

```
"resources": [
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
                    "sku": {
                        "name": "[parameters('skuName')]",
                        "tier": "[parameters('skuTier')]"
                    },
                    "name": "[parameters('LoadBalancerName')]",
                    "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
                    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                    "properties": {
                        "frontendIPConfigurations": [
                            {
                                "name": "[parameters('name')]",
                                "properties": { 
                                    "publicIPAddress": {
                                        "id":  "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',parameters('publicIpName'))]"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "dependsOn": []
                }
            ]
```

**

Comment: we can. but i need to do it with ARM template only.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add another configuration:

```
"frontendIPConfigurations": [
    {
        "name": "[parameters('name')]",
        "properties": { 
            "publicIPAddress": {
                "id":  "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',parameters('publicIpName'))]"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "[parameters('secondIP')]",
        "properties": { 
            "publicIPAddress": {
                "id":  "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',parameters('secondIp'))]"
            }
        }
    },
]
```

Comment: this is true. But only possible in the case when we know that we have to add only 2 IPs. what if we do not know, how many IPs to be added.